# Why were 'business jet' airliner designs so popular in the past?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, airliner, jet, private-jets

Let's look at [the MD-83](http://imgproc.airliners.net/photos/airliners/2/8/8/2193882.jpg?v=v40) (was Microsoft too poor or they lazily didn't want to waste time to make it flyable in FS2004/FSX?) and the [Learjet 35](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa150.jpg) (yes I used FS95/FS98 in the past).

Now, there are some "samish" things:

- Engines on the back of the fuselage
- Vertical stabilizers on the top of the rudder (maybe because engines take space in the back of the airliner?)
- Wings on the back of the plane (let's be honest, the first time I saw that I felt like "How did this fly?" only to realize it was made in order to put CoMass near to the CoLift
- Front of the plane is extremely long compared to the back of it (by back I mean the place that the wings and engine are on)
- Engines are SLIGHTLY tilted to the ground

Why was this 'business jet' design so popular in the past for airliners?

Comment: [Possible dupe of this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1917/why-do-large-aircraft-have-their-engines-mostly-on-the-wings-while-smaller-ones) as well as [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/how-does-the-mounting-location-of-a-jet-engine-affect-aircraft-performance) and more info in [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25636/why-are-modern-regional-jet-designs-shifting-towards-under-wing-engines)

Comment: Now we have 4 interconnected questions on the whole exchange
Lets forget it ok ?